# How to use gdbclient to debug the kernel on Nexus 7?

Tags: android, linux, gdb, kernel, qemu

I have all the code of nexus 7 on my machine and a rooted device.

I can debug a user space application using gdbclient and gdbserver, but how can I exploit the gdbclient and gdbserver to debug the Kernel?

I saw [this](http://cs.gmu.edu/~astavrou/courses/ISA_673/Android_Debugging/Android_GDB.pdf) post but it explian how to do it QEMU, How can I debug the real board.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697754/android-kernel-debugging

Answer (score 0):

You do it either way, through gdbclient or through gdbserver

I prefer using gdbclient, its simpler and it requires less commands.

First making sure you adbd is running as root

```
    adb root
```

Second, shell into your device to find out the app name you want to debug with

```
    adb shell
    ps // list all process running in the device
```

Third, exit the shell connect

```
    exit
```

last, connect to the app using gdbclient, ex connecting to "mediaserver"

```
    gdbclient mediaserver :5039 mediaserver
```

by default, remote gdb listen to port 5039, don't get confused with ddms, that's running at 5037 by default.
Hope this helps!

Comment: That's for an app - the question is asking about the kernel.