# Debugging Android kernel: Passing arguments to android kernel while booting

Tags: android, linux-kernel, kgdb

I am trying to get kgdb working with Android kernel using http://bootloader.wikidot.com/android:kgdb. I got stucked at following step:

```
    Configure kernel command line

    Specify ttyGS0 as the kgdboc device. Add the following into the kernel command line (possibly in BoardConfig.mk)

    kgdboc=ttyGS0 kgdbretry=4

    The second option "kgdbretry=4" is a new parameter added to kgdboc.c. 
    It means that if kgdb cannot find the device "ttyGS0" in early boot, 
    it will retry once after the specified number of seconds. 
    This is a work-around if the USB device is not immediately initialized during system boot.
```

Could anybody please tell me which BoardConfig.mk is it referring? Or is there any other method for passing these arguments to the kernel while booting?

Comment: There will be no uniform answer for "Android" - it depends on the bootloader and related systems used on a given device and install.

Answer (score 0):

An old post, but I've been looking at KGDB recently so thought I'd share:

For Android, I've been passing boot params in via the bootimg.cfg file which can be specified when you create (or update) your boot image. For example, I am updating an existing boot image with a new config file and new kernel using the following:

```
abootimg -u boot.img -f bootimg.cfg -u zImage-dtb
```

One of the params within this config file is "cmdline" where you can append your options.

Alternatively, for a quick and dirty modification you can pass the '-c "param=value"' option to abootimg which will allow you to specify new options on the fly.

Comment: This would be more helpful if it contained a pointer to bootimg.cfg documentation (or an existing bootimg.cfg that can be edited).

Answer (score -1):

`http://www.stlinux.com/u-boot/kernel-booting`

You can Change kernel command line like this:

`setenv bootargs mem=128M kgdboc=ttyGS0 kgdbretry=4`

`saveenv`

you may need to delete `console=ttyAS0,115200` for kgdb to work properly.

Comment: Note that this answer is specific to some *unspecified* platform.  How the kernel gets loaded is not standard across Android in general.