# Linux Kernel Dynamic Debug settings - persist across a reset

Tags: android, linux-kernel

With Dynamic Debugging enabled in the Linux Kernel, I am able to control which prints show up by writing to /sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control. However, It seems that a reboot resets this file to its default settings (all prints disabled).

Is there a way to make the settings persist across a reset? I have a print which is emitted early in the boot process, and I am not able to get it to print, because the reboot disables this print in /sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control.

Comment: `sys` is a virtual file system created by the kernel on the fly. It is by definition volatile. Are you developing a kernel module, or a userspace application? Do you need the output only for yourself (debugging), or should it be portable?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to add `dyndbg='your query here'` to the kernel command line using the bootloader configuration or manual options entry feature. This will vary with the bootloader although grub is the most common one

If you are using grub as a bootloader you would have to add it to the kernel command line in `/boot/grub/grub.conf` for the particular kernel you are launching at bootup.

A blog article about this can be found [here](http://burzalodowa.wordpress.com/2013/09/18/how-to-enable-and-tune-dynamic-debugging-for-xhci/). In particular it gives this example:

```
dyndbg='module xhci_hcd +p'
```

The article also discusses modifying grub as well.

This [kernel howto](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/dynamic-debug-howto.txt?id=HEAD) about dynamic debugging has useful information about dyndbg. This section applies

> To activate debug messages for core code and built-in modules during
>   the boot process, even before userspace and debugfs exists, use
>   dyndbg="QUERY", module.dyndbg="QUERY", or ddebug_query="QUERY"
>   (ddebug_query is obsoleted by dyndbg, and deprecated).  QUERY follows
>   the syntax described above, but must not exceed 1023 characters.  Your
>   bootloader may impose lower limits.
>
> These dyndbg params are processed just after the ddebug tables are
>   processed, as part of the arch_initcall.  Thus you can enable debug
>   messages in all code run after this arch_initcall via this boot
>   parameter.
>
> On an x86 system for example ACPI enablement is a subsys_initcall and
>      dyndbg="file ec.c +p"
>   will show early Embedded Controller transactions during ACPI setup if
>   your machine (typically a laptop) has an Embedded Controller.
>   PCI (or other devices) initialization also is a hot candidate for using
>   this boot parameter for debugging purposes.
>
> If foo module is not built-in, foo.dyndbg will still be processed at
>   boot time, without effect, but will be reprocessed when module is
>   loaded later.  dyndbg_query= and bare dyndbg= are only processed at
>   boot.

Comment: Good idea - it might have been clearer to say that you can add it **to the kernel command line** *using* the bootloader configuration or manual options entry feature of the bootloader.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am developing for Android, and I am not sue how to add this to the kernel command line. I have seen that for some boards, this is done using the device tree:
 chosen {
  bootargs = "...";
 };

However, This would require recompiling the kernel. Is there some way to do this on Android without recompilation?

Comment: See this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973701/debugging-android-kernel-passing-arguments-to-android-kernel-while-booting

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I'm new to SO, and I just noticed your replies now :)

I've tried these commands at the adb terminal:
    setenv bootargs dyndbg='module xhci_hcd +p'
    saveenv

but it says that saveenv is not a known command. I searched online, and it looks like this is a uboot command, but it seems like my device is using fastboot and not uboot. Should I be trying to modify the kernel command line using fastboot? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can have *dynamic_debug* for some kernel module *foo* activated automatically during boot using the `/etc/modprobe.d/` directory.

```
### BEGIN prerequisite
# in case module "foo" is not yet automatically loaded during boot,
# then make it load during boot:
# create a file /etc/modules-load.d/foo.conf with contents "foo"
echo "foo" | sudo tee /etc/modules-load.d/foo.conf
### END prerequisite

# create a configuration file to activate dynamic debug for module "foo"
# at its "module initialization time"
echo "options foo dyndbg=+p" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/foo.conf
```

Reference: [*Debug Messages at Module Initialization Time* from kernel.org documentation](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/dynamic-debug-howto.html#debug-messages-at-module-initialization-time).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as a part of post boot script. Say after Android boots(since i see Android tag added here), it runs certain sh scripts as a part of init procedure. Modify the sh files with the dynamic debug commands added and push it in and reboot .

Refer here for post boot script files info.
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6558/how-can-i-run-a-script-on-boot

Comment: Yes, if the issue happens *after* the point at which the script could run.  But it sounds like it might be happening before.

Comment: I am not quite sure of that. The write to the dynamic debug control entries is possible if Android shell has come up. Since shell has come up, by this time script should have run. But as u said, if it occurs before then this technqiue is not of much use, but it offers the advantage of not compiling things again

Comment: I read the question as being motivated by a desire to debug something in the kernel itself, so I think there's a high likelihood that no userspace process yet exists.  I have to admit if I'd been stuck on this for the past two weeks, I would have long ago made a temporary patch to whatever code checks this setting to find it always activated, and moved on to solving my actual problem before setting it back.